# Does the charge leakage of capacitors lead to photon emission?

Tags: photons, charge, capacitance, photon-emission

Capacitors will leak charge over time. This charge is basically electrical current leaking through insulating layer of the capacitor. I am wondering, if there is some emission of photons as there is is a potential acceleration of the electrons that are part of the leakage?

Sorry if there are major logical mistakes in my assumptions as I am not a physicist.

Comment: When the capacitor discharges, it heats up (energy conservation!). That heat can escape in form of radiation to the environment. It does not have to (it can also escape as thermal movement of e.g. air), but it can, so it "depends".

Answer (score 1):

In principle any acceleration of an electron causes some radiation, and an electron has to accelerate in order to leak from one plate to the other. However:

1. the velocities, and therefore the accelerations, of electrons in electrical circuits are small. Calculating the [electron drift velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity) is an exercise routinely given to students and the results tend to be fractions of a millimetre per second.
2. the radiation from an accelerating charge is negligible unless the acceleration is very high. For example [see my calculation here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/259642/energy-of-an-accelerated-charge/259664#259664).

So, in the situation you describe, to say that the radiation is utterly negligible would be a considerable understatement.